# Set an array blank in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to make an array blank in javascript

```
array = [];
```

or

```
array.length = 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: the first one makes a blank array, the second one blanks an array

Comment: It depends entirely upon whether you want to clear the current array so anyone else who has a reference to this array will see the cleared array or whether you want to create a new array and anyone who had references to the previous array will not be affected at all.  There's a big difference if others have a reference to this array.  If there are no other references to this array, then there is no functional difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use

```
array.length = 0;
```

as

```
array = [];
```

makes a new blank array that is empty

Comment: that sounds like one is going to nuke references to the array that other scopes may have, the second is not going to do so (but this is a guess, i'm not familiar with this).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use

```
array.length = 0;
```

not sure it matters

Comment: it matters if you are relying on prototypical inheritance within application. Emptying an array will maintain that inheritance whereas replacing it as a new object won't

Answer (score -2):

I believe the right way is:

```
array = [];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  You're just making a random guess.